# how to store $_POST values to save in a file line by line

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a PHP form and I want to save the selected values to a file one in a line. I am not very much used with PHP.

Right now, my script is storing data in one line with many other characters included. Below is the code I am using in the action.php

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    $o = json_encode($_POST);
    file_put_contents('data.txt',$o);

    die();
}
```

The output I am receiving in data.txt is like below.

> {"formDoor":["phpandmysql.tk\r\n","mytestdomainjordi\r\n","my1domain\r\n","ihatelinux\r\n","php1andmysql.tk\r\n","lubitz.co\r\n","testereed.com\r\n"],"formSubmit":"Submit"}

What I would like to get is something like this:

```
phpandmysql.tk
mytestdomainjordi
my1domain
ihatelinux
php1andmysql.tk
lubitz.co
testereed.com
```

**EDIT**

FORM:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("newtest1.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {?>
    <form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">
<?php
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="<?php echo $line; ?>"/><?php echo $line; ?><br />
<?php
    }
}
?>
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<?php
fclose($handle);

?>
```

I googled to come this far, can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Concatenate an `"\n"` or PHP_EOL and lose `json_encode` if you don't need it.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, could you please rewrite the code and post it? (not used with PHP coding)

Comment: Add your HTML form in your question. You're making everyone guess.

Comment: added it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"formDoor" is a key in your $_POST associative array (which is similar to a dictionary here). You can access it via $_POST['formDoor'], and check for its existence via isset($_POST['formDoor']).
 Outputting the formDoor parameter to the file can be done like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['formDoor'])) {
    $formDoor = $_POST['formDoor'];
    // check if the formDoor field is actually an array
    if(is_array($formDoor)) {
        // combine the array values into a string
        $data = implode('',$formDoor);
        file_put_contents('data.txt', $data);           
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting an output. My expectation is not getting the output to a file. Please see the question, I need the selected values to be written in the file line by line without any other characters. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The title of the question and the sample code you posted tell that you need the data written to a files, which is what the code snippet I gave you does.

Comment: I am sorry if my comment/topic misleaded. I am able to write to the file already. My concern is to write the inputs from form only to the file line by line. I think I have explained it well in the question. Seems title is misleading. I edited the title.

Comment: Does or doesn't my answer solve your problem? If not, please let me know the exact problems you face with my code. Otherwise I won't be able to help you.

Comment: I am sorry, I did some mistake somewhere. I completely removed the file and pasted yours and it worked. Seems some mistakes was done in my end earlier. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$result="";

foreach ($_POST["formDoor"] as $key => $value) {
    $result.=$value. "\n";
}
file_put_contents('data.txt',$result);
```

Comment: Tried above, but getting error in browser "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in...." I just pasted above code in the action.php between <?php and ?>

Comment: Just needs a semicolon at the end of line 4

Comment: *"Just needs a semicolon at the end of line 4"* - Not just that. Actually, `\n` do not get parsed in single quotes and will write `\n` inside the file rather than a new line (*remember that*). I've fixed both, that and the missing semi-colon. It needs to be inside double quotes.

Comment: Well, the error is gone. But I am not getting expected result. The output of data.txt is just:


Array
Submit

Comment: try this new code,instead `$_POST` use `$_POST["formDoor"]`

Comment: @ Fred -ii this mistake is very bad for you ;)

Comment: @ ashkufaraz : got this result. That is not what I am expecting.

["crisiswhatcrisis\r\n","phpandmysql.tk\r\n","mytestdomainjordi\r\n","my1domain\r\n","lubitz\r\n","lubitz\r\n","testereed\r\n","mhtest2\r\n"]

Comment: this output is equal to `newtest1.txt` and it is correct

Comment: you muse remove double `<?php echo $line; ?>` in value of `formDoor`

Comment: newtest1.txt is the file from the form is fetching the data and displaying while I access form in browser. It doesn't have anything to do with the checkbox-form.php
I removed it. Did this help in what I am expecting?

Comment: i does not understand

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $result="";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
       $result .= $key. " = ". $value. "\r\n";
    }
    file_put_contents('data.txt',$result);
}
```

Comment: well, this gave me result in data.txt as::

formDoor = Array
formSubmit = Submit